# JavaCC Choice Conflict Error

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

I am just messing around with JavaCC for my own language and am having trouble figuring out why I keep getting a choice conflict errors in this code below,

```
void term() :
{}
{
  factor()
  ( //choice conflict here
    (< PLUS > | < MINUS >) factor()
  )*
}


void id() :
{}
{
  < LETTERS >
  ( //choice conflict here
    < LETTERS > | < NUMBERS >
  )*
}
```

The LETTERS and NUMBERS are simply just "A"-"Z", "a"-"z" and "0"-"9". If anyone could possibly help that'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a problem within the hidden part of your grammer. I used your productions and built this simple working grammar file (JavaCC 5).
By the way you should not use productions (**id**) to accept identifiers. Instead you should build for this "words" of your language separate tokens like:

```
TOKEN:
{
    < SIMPLE_INTEGER: ( <NUMBERS> )+ >
    | < SIMPLE_IDENTIFIER: ( <LETTERS> )+ ( <NUMBERS> | <LETTERS>)* >
}
```

Now you can build productions using `<SIMPLE_INTEGER>` to accept an integer or `<SIMPLE_IDENTIFIER>` to accept an identifier.

This is the working grammar file with your productions.

```
options {
    STATIC = true;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(MyParser)
public class MyParser {
} 
PARSER_END(MyParser)

TOKEN : {
  <PLUS: "+">
| <MINUS: "-">
}

TOKEN: {
    <LETTERS: ["a"-"z", "A"-"Z"] >
|    <NUMBERS: ["0" - "9"] >
}

void factor() : {}
{
  (<NUMBERS>)+
}

void term() : {}
{
  factor() ( (<PLUS> | <MINUS>) factor() )*
}

void id() : {}
{
  <LETTERS> ( <LETTERS> | <NUMBERS> )*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that can follow a term can start with a plus or with a minus.  Thus the parser can not decide on the basis of the next token whether to (re)enter the loop or to stop parsing the term and move on to that other thing.

There is a similar problem with id.  Something that can follow an id can start with a letter or with a number.

Probably in your language there is the possibility of having two expressions in row.